# setting computed property in a SwiftUI view doesn't compile

Tags: swift, swiftui, computed-properties

Trying to set the computed property s in a SwiftUI view gets compiler error "Cannot assign to property: 'self' is immutable".
How do I have to I call the setter?

```
struct Test: View{
  @State var _s = "test"
  @State var _s2 = true
  private var s : String
  { get { _s }
    set (new)
    { _s = "no test"
      _s2 = false
      // do something else
    }
  }

  var body: some View
  { Text("\(s)")
    .onTapGesture {
      self.s = "anyting"  // compiler error
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You're trying actually to replicate `@State` behaviour... why? View is struct, value, it cannot modify itself from inside, that's why there is @State - it is for what you try to do. Just use it.

Comment: @Asperi I want to change some other states when setting s, I will extend the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha... I see. Just use non mutating set

```
  private var s : String
  { get { _s }
    nonmutating set (new)
    { _s = "no test"
      _s2 = false
      // do something else
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That is, why you already have @State property wrapper in your View.

```
struct Test: View{
  @State var s = "test"
    var body: some View {
    Text("\(s)")
    .onTapGesture {
      self.s = "anyting"  // compiler error
    }
  }
}
```

You able to change s directly from your code because s is wrapped with @State.

this is functional equivalent of the above

```
struct Test: View{
    let s = State<String>(initialValue: "alfa")
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(s.wrappedValue)")
                .onTapGesture {
                    self.s.wrappedValue = "beta"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or if Binding is needed

```
struct Test: View{
    let s = State<String>(initialValue: "alfa")
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("label", text: s.projectedValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to change some other states when setting s, I will extend the example